# List lastest modified or newly created files in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, directory, date

How to list modified or newly created files or directories in linux. So that I can trigger another command or shell script for another task.
     for eg. A file a.txt and test.txt are modified and I want to find the lasted changed files using linux cmd and then trigger a restart.sh script(say) to get changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this, but here is an example in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob
import time
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mtimes = dict()

    while True:
        for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
            if f not in mtimes:
                mtimes[f] = os.path.getmtime(f)

            if mtimes[f] != os.path.getmtime(f):
                print("File {} was modified. Executing restart.sh.".format(f))
                mtimes[f] = os.path.getmtime(f)                
                output = subprocess.check_output('./restart.sh')
                print(output)

        time.sleep(1)
```

You probably need to adjust it to your environment:

- `glob.glob('*.txt')` is the search pattern for the files you wish to monitor.
- `subprocess.check_output('./restart.sh')` is where you call the script. It may reside somewhere else.
- `time.sleep(1)` is the delay (in seconds) between checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with inotifywait. They look at the system calls for create,modify,delete,move and you can script in the shell what to do when it is detected